# Can the use of lang="en-US" on a blog affect international traffic?

Tags: seo, google, blog, internationalization, geotargeting

We have our main domain ranking in Google for 100+ countries. We have WordPress blog setup for this domain which is at: `example.com/Blog`

For this blog, we had many keyword rankings in various countries in Google. As you can see in the screen capture, we have started losing ranking for few countries:

[image: ranking down screencapture]

Also, we are not getting ranked (in Google Search) for countries (except USA).

I just noticed that for this blog, we have `"lang="en-US">"`, could this be the cause of this issue? Does this mean we are targeting people in the U.S. only by using this tag?

Answer (score 2):

> `<link rel="alternate" href="example.com/pt/" hreflang="pt-pt" />` The
>   same annotations should appear on your French and Portuguese
>   homepages.
>
> It is still possible that Mexican, French Canadian, and Brazilian
>   customers could see your site (remember, hreflang is a signal not a
>   directive)

Source: https://moz.com/learn/seo/hreflang-tag

Your tag is targeting the USA, which could indeed negatively influence traffic from other countries as Google may assume this means that your page is really just for USA visitors.

I recommend that you change the langtag to `lang="en">` instead

Comment: Thank you for your help, Michael ! If I change the lang="en", can it cause traffic decrease in USA visitors or any other actions required which I need to take to do it properly?

Comment: hi Michael, I am awaiting your input on this?

Comment: I can't guarantee that you won't experience a traffic drop from USA visitors by changing lang from en-us to en, as you are currently targeting the USA. As a general rule, if your website is in English and the pages are good for global traffic, then it's correct to use lang=en. If your website is in English and the pages are mostly just useful for Americans, then you might want lang=en-us. I find that it's better to implement code properly according to Google's standards than it is to try and game the system. In other words, it's best to do what you think is correct.